# How to fix Rigify's finger?

Tags: rigging

I rig my character's fingers with rigify. It took me a long time to match every joint to mesh. Then I use Generate Rig. But the finger's axis is very messy. After that, I go back to the bones and use Shift+N to use Recalculation all the finger bones. Then click Generate Rig again. But the axis of the fingers is still messed up.[image][image][image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rigify does not use the rolls of the bones of the meta rig, but rather, as with the elbows and knees, tries to guess the direction of flexion based on an existing slight bend of the fingers.

For this to work, the bones must be arranged in a perfect line, i.e. they must not deviate to the left or right. Otherwise, the control bone is rotated and the finger bends exactly in this direction and thus twists.

[image: bad alignment example]

When your character model is not in a straight T pose but in an A pose it's not so easy to align the bones properly.

But you can add a little cube, scale it like a finger and align it to the finger. Then set the viewport's view to one of its sides. Use the viewport's menu: *View > Align View > Align View to Active > Top* or just <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Numpad 7</kbd>.

[image: alignment of the view]

Now you can set the *Transformation orientation* to `View` and the *Transform Pivot Point* to the `3D Cursor`. Select the tip of the finger bone, move the 3D Cursor to it (<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>), select the three bones of the finger, and align them in a line by scaling them along the view's Y-axis to 0: <kbd>S</kbd><kbd>Y</kbd><kbd>0</kbd>.

Use the 3D Cursor to align the palm bone to the finger bones.

[image: correct alignment]

Side view:

[image: side view]

Before you try out the generated rig, don't forget to reset the *Transformation orientation* to `Global` or `Local` and the *Transform Pivot Point* to `Individual Origins` so you can rotate the bones properly in *Pose* mode.

To make a fist, scale down the red control bones, and rotate the green control bones at the knuckles (*Finger Details* layer). Move them a little if needed to make a tight fist.

[image: thumbs up animation]