# Having trouble balling my character's fist

Tags: rigging, armature, bones, pose-mode

I am trying to ball my character's fist but his fingers appear deformed/squished when I try to do so. Do you recommend I add extra bones or redo his fingers? I would appreciate any feedback. Thanks. [image]

https://wetransfer.com/downloads/9299dbdc22a0ec94fb2bada403f9019020220703170911/d38f123d469b1c09f07e480deefb25a720220703170954/4b7f7a

Comment: Sidenote: The *Subdivision Surface* modifier should be below the *Armature* modifier. The stack works top-down and if you have the *Armature* modifier on top it can use the low-poly mesh and its original weights to deform it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are your topology and bones:

[image]

I think that:

- You need to put the *Armature* modifier above the *Subdivision Surface*, and also activate the *Preserve Volume* option of the *Armature* modifier.
- You need to make sure that the head and tail of your bones match the joints
- You need more topology around the joints so that they bend smoothly, so bevel the joints:

[image]

- At last you need to assign the vertices to the good vertex groups. You probably need to do it manually because parenting *With Automatic Weights* will mess up for such a complicated part, so select the vertices, go into the *Object Data panel > Vertex Groups*, select the correct group, click on *Assign*. It should give something like that at the end:

[image]

I've given a *Copy Rotation* constraint to the second and third phalanx bone so that you just need to rotate the first one to make the others bend. Also you could segment each phalanx bone so that they bend more roundly.

Comment: I would align the 3 bones of each finger in a straight line (https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/258576/how-to-fix-rigifys-finger/259369#259369) and add 5 more bones for the palm (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hand#/media/File:Handskelett.png). They limit the influence of the finger bones and allow the thumb to deform the palm mesh when the thumb touches the pinky. Also, calculate the bone rolls to ensure the finger stays straight when it bents.

Comment: Ok thanks for the precisions  ;)

Comment: Both answers are brilliant! Thank you so much!