# How to Fixing rigify errors on mouths and fingers

Tags: mesh, rigging, armature, error, rigify

Would you mind telling me how I can fix the rigify on the mouth and fingers? Does anyone know the answer to this question? Here are the pictures.
[image]

[image]

Make sure you add a picture/gif explanation to help me better understand and show how you make it so I can comprehend how to make it myself.

Comment: It looks like the weights are off. Automatic weights should work for the fingers when [the bones are aligned properly](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/258576/how-to-fix-rigifys-finger/259369). This seems to be the case. Are you sure the mesh of fingers has no flipped normals?

Comment: The eyes, eyebrows, eyelids, and mouth usually need some manual weight painting. You can make a short animation (close -> open) and then fix the weights. Have a look here: https://youtu.be/UpAxY519IJU?t=251 and https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/215623/107598

Comment: Are you using Voxel heat addon fore the weights?