# Rig does not move the body

Tags: rigging

I followed a Youtube tutorial and with the help of rigidify I wanted to rig the body. I don't understand why, even though I followed all the steps, my mesh doesn't move.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please share your Blend file via https://blend-exchange.com/ following the instructions on the page and someone can have a look.

Comment: Looks like you are trying to move the leg with the FK controls (green) in the 2nd screenshot. By default, the IK controls (red) are active in Rigify. Try the red foot and hand controls to move the limbs. If you want to use the FK controls you need to switch them in the viewports side panel ("N-panel").

Comment: @Blunder, I tried with the so called fk controls. Still it didn't work. But I assume its due to my limited knowledge. Maybe I try too much. Would there be a tutorial or course you would recommend for learning rigging/ animation?

Comment: No worries, practice makes perfect ;-) The main problem is that the mesh has intersecting geometry around the mouth, armpits, and crotch area. This makes the calculation of the weights fail. Especially, the lips/mouth corners seem to cause the infamous "[Heat Weighting: Failed to find solution for one or more bones](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/15964/107598)" error that you can see in the status bar. If you separate the lips/inner mouth then the "Parent > With Automatic Weight" operation works. The mouth and the eyes usually require some manual weight painting.

Comment: The mesh has a few unnecessary intersecting loose parts (right armpit, crotch area). I would remove this first (Edit mode, deselect everything with Alt+A, select a vertice of the body, press L to Selected Linked = the whole body without the loose parts, hover the mouse over the eyes, and press L again to select them, too. Then hide the selected mesh (key H). Select everything left (key A). This is the stuff you don't want. Delete it (X) and unhide everything (Alt+H)). -- Additionally, you can convert the mesh to quads to work with it more easily (select all A, then Tris to Quads Alt+J)

Comment: For the eyes have a look here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/211089/107598. The mouth works similarly. If you have separated it, just join it back when you have parent the body. Don't forget to merge the mouth and face (select the verts and press key M > Merge by Distance). Then you can weight-paint it manually. -- For the fingers you need to adjust the bones a bit more else they bend in a weird way: https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/258576/107598. Make sure the leg bones are not X-legs or O-legs. They must be straight like the fingers but bent a little bit (from the side).

Comment: Additional helpful videos on how to fix the eyelids, mouth, teeth, and eyeballs (and an alternative solution for the fingers): https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3GZE5bjZXbA&list=PLowasMviFd8AdzQHiH-gJPxEwN_Chjv0b&index=7&t=616s. And CGDive's Rigify series: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-JSFcSxsaTs&list=PLdcL5aF8ZcJv68SSdwxip33M7snakl6Dx. I hope that helps

Comment: @Blunder, uff maybe I should try something easier next. Thank u very much for your help. :) I think I'm gonna check the tutorial series next.

Comment: A bit late but here is another trick that works for this model: First clear the mesh's parent (Alt+P), apply the scale to the armature and the mesh, and move the mesh into the center (X-axis), it's a bit off. Now the trick is to scale up the mesh and the armature by 10, then parent them with automatic weights, and finally clear the scale again (Alt+S). Scaled up the automatic weight calculation works. -- I also recommend starting with a metarig that has a complete set of hand bones. In your metarig, the palm bones are missing for some reason. This will not work properly.