Rigify controllers not moving arms
I used human model with human pre-made bone structure. I aligned it with my model, used Rigify and parented (with automatic weights) the created rig to my model.

Most controllers move the model as they should but there are three green circle controllers from shoulder to the wrist (that have a center green line that goes through the arm) that don't move the model if I move them, and if I move the hand with other controllers, the green line with circle controllers stay in place. Can I fix this?
blend file: https://we.tl/t-O0Z62vHN3F

Hello and welcome. While files, images, and external videos or links may be helpful additions they should not be the only way to obtain information about your issue. Don't make understanding your question rely on downloading a file, watching a video or visiting an external site. Use the builtin tools to upload images or gifs, along with thoroughly explaining the problem in written form so it can be indexed and searched for thus helping future visitors with similar issues.

Hi. That's normal. The green control are the FK controls. The red ones are IK controls. You can switch between them and make them snap to each other with the Rigify buttons in the side panel (N). There are also buttons to hide them. I've added a screenshot to your question that shows the buttons. The switch is called "IK-FK (hand-R)". Enter 1.0 to switch to FK. The snaps are below. Make sure to select an arm bone to see it.

For better performance and results, I would swap the Armature and the Smooth on the modifier stack of the model. The stack works from top to bottom, and you want to use the Armature modifier to deform the mesh first, and then the Smooth modifier to smooth it, not the other way around. Overall, the deformations look good, with the exception of the index finger and toes. You might want to optimize the bone layout of the metarig and regenerate the rig. Here are a few tips for the fingers: https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/258576/107598
